# What happened to 'Copy Public Gallery Link' for folders in Photos in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I've been trying to figure out how to use the **Photos** folder properly, but it does not seem to contain the functionality that is mentioned on various websites.

From what I've read, you are supposed to create a folder within the 'Photos' folder. At that point, it becomes a public gallery for which you can access the context menu item **Copy Public Gallery Link**.

However, I do not have this context menu item. 
[image]

I found a topic on the DropBox forum, but it is 2 years old. Even the various website information mentioned is over a year old.

I found a topic from this year on SuperUser that mentions about the **Share link** menu item. I understand that this functionality is basically the same as **Copy Public Gallery Link**, however, the key difference is that it opens the website for which I need to click **Copy link to this page** link, which then adds it to the clipboard.

[image]

My primary questions are:

- Did they phase out the **Copy Public Gallery Link** from the context menu entirely?
- If not, is there a way to re-enable this menu item?
- If not, am I using the **Photos** folder properly?
- Lastly, if there is no way to get this menu item, is there some kind of script or hack-around that will let me simplify the **Share link** + **Copy link to this page** functionality without requiring it to open my web browser?

Note: I had to edit my post to remove other website links that I mention since I'm considered a 'New User' here and am only able to post 2 hyperlinks. Sorry.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the old link is gone for good: https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of your post, you were correct - you had to go to the website to get a link.  Not anymore, though: https://blog.dropbox.com/2013/06/even-quicker-sharing-from-the-desktop/

Comment: I noticed this recently too. Thanks for link. Marking this as the answer.